# How do I provide auth data for Firebase Firestore rest api call

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, authorization

Here is my REST API GET: [https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{myProjectId}/databases/(default)/documents/books](https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/%7BmyProjectId%7D/databases/(default)/documents/books)

My goal is of course to retrieve documents from my `books` collection. The REST API docs are not great. I understand how to get an `access_token` given the `Firestore` scope, but how do I actually provide that in the `GET`? Do I do `Bearer {access_token}` as `Authorization` header? Do I also provide `api={apiKey}` as a query string param? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `authorization` header. Here's a `curl` request for the same:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/databases/(default)/documents/books' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]'
```

If you still get `403 - Forbidden` errors, then the token maybe expired or the security rules don't allow the read operaion.

Comment: I recall reading that the security rules only apply if you're using the `npm` libraries, and that the security rules do not apply for rest calls. Does that ring a bell? I may have misread that.

Comment: @IanDavis no, security rules work on REST API as well. At least the Firebase ID Tokens.

Comment: does [ACCESS_TOKEN] = Firebase ID Token? Or given a "Firebase ID Token" do I need to retrieve a separate access token? Consistency of terms would be great if Google could do that!

Comment: @IanDavis you can use either. Firebase ID token or access tokens from Google OAuth. Both are different. But in my answer I've considered the Firebase ID token from Firebase auth.

Comment: Do you know what my rule should look like if I'm using `user.getIdToken()`?

```
match /links {
  allow read: if request.auth.idToken is not null ...?
}
```

Comment: @IanDavis if you want any authenticated users to read data then it should be `allow read: if request.auth != null;` There isn't any `idToken` property. It's `token` if you want to access more info. More info in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236761/discussion-between-ian-davis-and-dharmaraj).